# Check remote PowerShell session status in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-remoting

I create PowerShell Remoting session per the following code:

```
AuthenticationMechanism auth = AuthenticationMechanism.Negotiate;

WSManConnectionInfo ci = new WSManConnectionInfo(
    false,
    sRemote,
    5985,
    @"/wsman",
    @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";,
    creds);
ci.AuthenticationMechanism = auth;

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(ci);
runspace.Open();
PowerShell psh = PowerShell.Create();
psh.Runspace = runspace;
```

I have two questions, based on this code snippet:

1. I need to run this session over a long time; hence I need to make sure that remote session is alive. How can I do this?
2. Can I change the duration for which session should be kept alive?

Comment: Good question - just posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have two questions, I have two headings for separate responses.

### PowerShell Runspace State

You can examine the state of the PowerShell `Runspace` object by using the `State` property, which points to a value of the [`RunSpaceState` .NET enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspacestate%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
var IsOpened = runspace.RunspaceStateInfo.State == RunspaceState.Opened;
```

### Setting the IdleTimeout

If you want to set the `IdleTimeout` for the PowerShell session, then you need to:

1. Instantiate the [`PSSessionOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.remoting.pssessionoption%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class
2. Set the [`IdleTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.remoting.pssessionoption.idletimeout%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property
3. Call [`SetSessionOptions()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.wsmanconnectioninfo.setsessionoptions%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method on the `WSManConnectionInfo` object

Code:

```
var option = new PSSessionOption();            // Create the PSSessionOption instance
option.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60); // Set the IdleTimeout using a TimeSpan object
ci.SetSessionOptions(option);                  // Set the session options on the WSManConnectionInfo instance
```